# Unable to query Azure Blob Storage Using Query Blob Contents API if DelimitedTextConfiguration is provided

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Azure Query Blob Storage API is not working if DelimitedTextConfiguration is provided in InputSerialization tag. I have a CSV file in Azure Blob Storage, it works fine if DelimitedTextConfiguration is not specified in InputSerialization. But I need that to specify HasHeaders tag, since I want data to be column based and not numeric index based.

I am using this documentation for reference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-blob-contents

I am sending the following Query Request information.

Post: https://XXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXX.csv?sp=r&st=2021-07-10T08:27:15Z&se=2021-07-16T16:27:15Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=b&sig=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Headers:

```
x-ms-date:2021-07-09
x-ms-version:2020-08-04
Content-Type:application/xml; charset=UTF-8
```

Request Body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QueryRequest>
   <QueryType>SQL</QueryType>
   <Expression>select * from BlobStorage where transcation_id=1 limit 5</Expression>
   <InputSerialization>
      <Format>
         <Type>delimited</Type>
         <DelimitedTextConfiguration>
            <ColumnSeparator>,</ColumnSeparator>
            <FieldQuote>"</FieldQuote>
            <RecordSeparator>\n<RecordSeparator/>
            <EscapeChar>\</EscapeChar>
            <HasHeaders>True</HasHeaders>
         </DelimitedTextConfiguration>
      </Format>
   </InputSerialization>
   <OutputSerialization>
      <Format>
         <Type>json</Type>
         <JsonTextConfiguration>
            <RecordSeparator>,</RecordSeparator>
         </JsonTextConfiguration>
      </Format>
   </OutputSerialization>
</QueryRequest>
```

This request fails and give me error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidXmlDocument</Code>
    <Message>XML specified is not syntactically valid.
RequestId:1b6c5de1-601e-0060-126b-759c61000000
Time:2021-07-10T09:08:24.1321407Z</Message>
</Error>
```

I have tried by removing some subtags under DelimitedTextConfiguration, but nothing works, even if only DelimitedTextConfiguration is present with no child tag, it still throws same error.

Comment: The error may be due to the Tags inside  DelimitedTextConfiguration.  Try to add tags in correct format ,Use the predefined  Xml entities .   Please refer this github link for more details  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/format-delimited-text.md.  Also try with Switching to x-ms-version: 2020-10-02   ,Refer this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/versioning-for-the-azure-storage-services

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in RecordSeparator - you could either do:

```xml
  <RecordSeparator />
```

To use default newlines... otherwise through some trial and error you may need to see if either

`LF: "&#xA;"`
`CR: "&#xD;"`

```xml
<RecordSeparator>&#xA;</RecordSeparator>
```

I think there is some validation which is failing if it sees 2 characters though so if your CSV is windows based may need to use the default as I wasn't able to get CRLF to work:

Also `HasHeaders` should be lowercase `true`.