# Unable to construct Request Body XML for Azure Blob Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-rest-api

I have a csv file uploaded to Azure blob container. Im querying this file through an [Query Blob contents API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-blob-contents). Output response is JSON.

Issue is **Request Body XML is not working properly**. Im referring this [url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-blob-contents#request-body) to build xml.

[image]

When I try it, Im getting **400-XML specified is not syntactically valid.**

[image: eror]

My CSV file contents,

[image: input]

Please help to construct the Request body XML for above file. Also inside  I need to use WHERE clause for those csv headers.

Comment: please refer this similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68326359/unable-to-query-azure-blob-storage-using-query-blob-contents-api-if-delimitedtex

Comment: thread doesn't help. Still im gettin same error 
<InputSerialization>
        <Format>
            <Type>delimited</Type>
            <DelimitedTextConfiguration>
                <ColumnSeparator>&#44;</ColumnSeparator>
                <RecordSeparator>&#10;</RecordSeparator>
                <HasHeaders>true</HasHeaders>
            </DelimitedTextConfiguration>
        </Format>
    </InputSerialization>
Here **ColumnSeparator (its comma), RecordSeparator (its new line) doesn't work**. Am i missing anything ?

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases  the error  `specified is not syntactically valid`  seems to be with the  **`storage Version or api version`** being used .

*similar type cases:*

1. [ref1-invalidxmldocument-Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68889000/invalidxmldocument-xml-specified-is-not-syntactically-valid)
2. [arm-templates-storageaccountsfileservices-error(Microsoft Q&A)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-blob-contents)

So in some cases the blob might be  already deployed resource and may have different version.So please try changing to the compatible version and also check all the other parameters given in the request according to the [***`query-blob-contents`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-blob-contents)

I tried in my environment by using the request where sas is taken from the uploaded blob.
somethinglike this to get proper request with correct versions

```
https://<acctname>.blob.core.windows.net/democontainer/sample.csv?sp=r&st=2022-07-28T11:50:45Z&se=2022-07-28T19:50:45Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=xxxxxxxx%2Bxxx%3D
```

(or)

you can provide the proper parameters with compatible version  as the record separator and column separator may not be valid in few versions.

[image]

I had similar csv file in azure.

[image]

Tried with same xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<QueryRequest>
<QueryType>SQL</QueryType>
<Expression>select * from BlobStorage where </Expression>
<InputSerialization>
<Format>
<Type>csv</Type>
<DelimitedTextConfiguration>
<ColumnSeparator>string</ColumnSeparator>
<RecordSeparator>string</RecordSeparator>
<HasHeaders>True</HasHeaders>
</DelimitedTextConfiguration>
</Format>
</InputSerialization>
<OutputSerialization>
<Format>
 <Type>json</Type>
</Format>
</OutputSerialization>
</QueryRequest>
```

[image]

> **If your using Azure.Storage.Blobs in other cases programatically, then try downgrade the version to see the changes or upgrade in some cases .**

**Reference**: [Query Blob Contents API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-blob-contents)

Comment: I tried SAS earlier, it worked for me. But in my case, i need to use headers(True) to use SQL queries with Where clause. Can you try with few header filters like (where hostname='abc') and return json response ?